# Google Apps Script Error: Missing permissio

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions

I am running an onEdit function in Google Apps Script and the function works except the part where it is supposed to send an email notification when changes are made on specific cells.

I keep on getting this error log:
"You do not have permission to call MailApp.sendEmail. Required permissions: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail"](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail%22)

I already added the necessary permissions to the appsscript.json manifest file but it still doesn't work:

> "oauthScopes": [
> "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
> "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail"
> ],

What am I missing?

I also tried to run any function manually to see if it would trigger any kind of authorization process, but it also didn't work out.

Comment: Search installable triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the description you are using [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) - they never ask user for authorization and cannot use services that require special permissions.

You need to use [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onEdit` trigger: `Script IDE` -> `Triggers` -> `+ Add Trigger`. You will be prompted for authorization when you install it and after that the trigger should work.

I also suggest renaming the function from `onEdit` to something else, otherwise it will run both as a simple (and error out) and installable trigger.

Comment: Sure! I tried this before and it does work. 

The problem is that I want to replicate this same script to a whole bunch of different spreadsheets (possibly using libraries)... and in that situation installable triggers do not work out.

Is there any other solution that would make this possible?

Comment: @RaulMarquez You cannot do it with a simple `onEdit` trigger.  If you need to install triggers at scale, you could create a setup function that will create a trigger programmatically with `ScriptApp.newTrigger()` ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newtriggerfunctionname)).  It will require additional permission: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp`.